# Titanium Backup - sync via Windows File Sharing (SMB) after backing up?

Tags: wi-fi, sync, titanium-backup

I have Titanium Backup Pro with sync after backup option, but I don't want to sync to clouds, instead I want it sync backups to my PC via SMB.
I also have Foldersync which supports SMB syncing but it works with scheduling only, what I need is syncing right after the backup procedure is done.
Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: *FolderSync* does support [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), and *Tasker* supports file events. Idea based on [a post](http://www.marshut.com/pumuw/respond-to-new-file.html):

> To detect the arival of a new file, use "File Modified" but long press the folder instead of selecting a file within it. now tasker will monitor changes to the folder.

So: Use *Tasker* to monitor *TiBu's* backup directory. If *Tasker* detects changes, give it a wait for 5 minutes (which should allow *TiBu* to finish the backup), then let it trigger *FolderSync* to synchronize with your Windows share:

- **Condition:**

  - Time → Between X and Z (optionally, to minimize battery consumption. X should be at least a few minutes *before* the scheduled backup, Z a few minutes *after*. Make sure that Z = the scheduled backup time plus the wait in below task plus some margin for the sync to complete)
  - Event → File Event → File Modified (select directory as described above)
- **Task:**

  - Tasker → Wait (5 min, or whatever you feel best)
  - Plugins → FolderSync → (whatever the action is called there)

Comment: Good idea, but I can just schedule foldersync a few minutes after titanium backup. This is close but not exactly what I want, I need it know when the backup's done and sync automatically :)

Comment: Sure it would be the simpler method to schedule it just a few minutes past the backup. But to know when the backup is done, that's a bit more tricky: you could use some variables, and a "multi-profile". One is watching that folder in 1-min-intervals, and increasing a variable whenever there's something changed. The other is watching that variable, triggers the backup when the var has not changed 3 times, and also resets that variable then. I'm just not sure if it's worth that trouble :)